# How to create multilevel figure / table numbers?

Tags: floats, numbering

How to create figure numbers like 1.1.1 and then 1.2.1, not 1.2.2?
I mean even if I added `\arabic{section}` into the command, the order of figures is still continuous, not accordingly rearranged by sections.
Is there any mistake I made? Below is the command line:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about what the numbers refer to . In '1.2.1' I guess the first number is the chapter. What about the other two?

Answer (score 8):

For numbering figures and tables per chapter you could use the command `\numberwithin` of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
```

amsmath is very recommendable if you write mathematical expressions in your document.

Alternatively, use the package [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) which is specialized in such manipulations of counters:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

Comment: Contrary to amsmath, chngcntr also provides a command for decoupling counters (`\counterwithout`).

Comment: *`chngcntr`* is also embedded in *`memoir`*

Comment: Perhaps you could also mention the keys `tablewithin=...`, and `figurewithin=...` from the `caption` package.

Comment: @Peter Grill: Yes, thanks, corrected. That package has a strange name, completely without vocals, inviting for typos.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by using the following piece of code

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Make sure to place the \numberwithin command before the renewcommand snippet, otherwise it won't work.