# Changing number within \numberwithin causes malfunction but no compile error

Tags: numbering, counters

An interesting one here. It could be a bug or I might be missing a trick. In my thesis I use `\numberwithin{}{}` to have numbering done within sections. Top level is chapter, so it goes `<chapter>.<section>.<table counter>`.

In my appendix, this is too much, so I only want numbering within the chapter i.e. `<chapter>.<table counter>`. Therefore numbering will run across different sections and the left most digit will go up when the chapter changes.

However, if I use `\numberwithin` after the appendix, then it subtly messes up the numbering. It gets the number of indices correct, however, the right most index doesn't change. My guess is, that it is confused and is still thinking it should be changing the third index (which isn't printed).

I have included a working example. Any one have a clue?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{table}{section}

\begin{document}
   \chapter{Thing}
      \section{the first section}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \section{second section}  

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

\appendix
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

   \chapter{first appendix chapter}
      \section{first appendix section}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \section{second appendix section}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \begin{table}[h!]
      \caption{wib}
         \begin{tabular}{c}
         hello
         \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [how to create multilevel figure table number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/how-to-create-multilevel-figure-table-numbers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the counter `figure` is bound to `section` and a later `\numberwithin` doesn't break this binding.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

...

\appendix
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
```

While `\counterwithin` is quite similar to `\numberwithin`, **amsmath** lacks the ability to unbind a counter from another.

Comment: Seems like **amsmath** should change `\numberwithin` to handle it. Your solution works though, much appreciated.

Comment: @aghsmith -- `\numberwithin` was designed to be used only in the preamble, although that isn't documented.  (i just checked with the maintainer; his response: "if it works, that would be a surprise.")  this matter has been posted to the `amsmath` requests list for reconsideration at the next overhaul.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : Was this ever updated? The current `amsmath` package documentation makes no mention of what you speak.  http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf

Comment: @kando -- no, this hasn't changed, and isn't likely to any time soon.  the staff with the ability to make such changes is limited, and other projects have been assigned higher priority by management.

Comment: @barbarabeeton : Could you weigh in on my similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264394/equation-number-syntax-section-subsection-subsubsection-equationnu

Comment: @kando -- i see a detailed answer there from christian hupfer.  does that do the job?  (if so, you should vote it up and give it the check mark.)

Comment: Important note: recent (post April 2019) versions of LaTeX have incorporated the features of `chngcntr`, so loading the package is no longer needed.