# Reset `equation` counter for any section change, regardless of section depth

Tags: numbering, counters

I would like the `equation` counter to reset automatically whenever a `\section` command is called, independent of section depth:

- `\section`
- `\subsection`
- `\subsubsection`
- `\paragraph`
- `\subparagraph`

### MWE Description:

The most brute force method would be to `\setcounter{equation}{0}` whenever a section command is called.  This method has been superceded by the `chngcntr` package.

Currently, the [`chngcntr`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr/chngcntr.pdf) package is used to reset the equation counter.  This will reset the counter automatically if the next section is at the same depth; however, the `\counterwithin*` command must be used each time the section depth is altered.

The current MWE code was originally developed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264402/76480) by user [`Christian Hupfer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer).

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}                   % margin/page layout settings
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}           % improved header commands. [supercedes `fancyhdr' package].

\usepackage{mathtools}                  % includes amsmath, supplements it.
\usepackage{chngcntr}                   % allows changing equation section depth mid-document
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% Margin Settings:
\KOMAoptions{fontsize   = 12pt    ,
             parskip    = half-   ,
             headheight = 1.000em , 
             footheight = 2.700em , 
             DIV        = current }

\geometry{letterpaper              ,
          hmargin      = 0.750in   ,
          tmargin      = 0.750in   ,
          bmargin      = 0.750in   ,
          headsep      = 1.000em   ,
          footskip     = 3.700em   } % [ = Footheight + Footsep]


%Initialize headers and footers
\chead{\normalfont Header 1 \\ Header 2}
\cfoot{\normalfont Footer 1 \\ Footer 2}
\ofoot{\normalfont Page \thepage}


% Section numbering: Format \paragraph like \subsection
\newcommand{   \subsubsubsection} [1] {    \paragraph{#1} }
\newcommand{\subsubsubsubsection} [1] { \subparagraph{#1} }

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}               %
  {\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}    %
  {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}    %
  {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}                 %
  {\normalfont\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}     }

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}               %
  {\@startsection{subparagraph}{4}{\z@}    %
  {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}    %
  {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}                 %
  {\normalfont\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}     }

\makeatother






% Equation Numbering
\let\origtheequation\theequation
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\xequationFormat} {\determineSection-\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\determineSection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}    > 0
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection} > 0
  \ifnum\value{paragraph}     > 0
  \ifnum\value{subparagraph}  > 0 \thesubparagraph
  \else                           \theparagraph      \fi
  \else                           \thesubsubsection  \fi
  \else                           \thesubsection     \fi
  \else                           \thesection        \fi
}

\newcommand{\eqSectionDepth} [2] { \counterwithout*{equation}{#1}\counterwithin*{equation}{#2} }
% syntax: \equationNumbering{oldSectionDepth}{newSectionDepth}


% For demonstration purposes only:
\newtoggle{enableFormat}
\newcommand{\toggleformat}%
{ \iftoggle{enableFormat}%
  {%
    \togglefalse{enableFormat}%               % 0
    \let\theequation\origtheequation% 
  }%
  {%
    \toggletrue{enableFormat}%                % 1
    \let\theequation\xequationFormat%
  }%
}






\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\section{Level 1}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\subsection{Level 2}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\subsubsection{Level 3}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\subsubsubsection{Level 4}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\subparagraph{Level 5}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\clearpage

\toggleformat

\section{Level 1}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{section}{subsection}
\subsection{Level 2}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{subsection}{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Level 3}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{subsubsection}{paragraph}
\subsubsubsection{Level 4}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{paragraph}{subparagraph}
\subparagraph{Level 5}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\eqSectionDepth{subparagraph}{section}

\clearpage

\section{Level 1}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{section}{subsection}
\subsection{Level 2}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{subsection}{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Level 3}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{subsubsection}{paragraph}
\subsubsubsection{Level 4}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}

\eqSectionDepth{paragraph}{subparagraph}
\subparagraph{Level 5}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x \end{equation}
\eqSectionDepth{subparagraph}{section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want all equations to be  `eq (1)`? :o)

Comment: @Bernard : Only if it's the first in the section ; j

Comment: @Bernard : Ultimately, I will be prepending the equation with the section number followed by a hyphen.

Comment: equations (3.2.5.1.2.1),  (3.2.5.1.3.1), (3.2.5.2.1.1) and so on? Nanonumbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a set of `\counterwithin*` instructions:

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}% Reset equation at \section
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}% Reset equation at \subsection
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsubsection}% Reset equation at \subsubsection
\counterwithin*{equation}{paragraph}% Reset equation at \paragraph
\counterwithin*{equation}{subparagraph}% Reset equation at \subparagraph
```

The starred version doesn't update `\theequation`. It's equivalent to

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\@addtoreset{equation}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{equation}{subsubsection}
\@addtoreset{equation}{paragraph}
\@addtoreset{equation}{subparagraph}
\makeatother
```

---

The latest (2015) release of LaTeX handles counter resetting slightly differently. Instead of resetting the counter to 0, it sets it to -1 followed by a `\stepcounter`. This performs a hierarchical cascading effect of counter resetting. As such, it suffices to use

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{subparagraph}
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{subparagraph}
\makeatother
```

Comment: These all stack with each other?

Comment: There's the reset code I've been looking for! And they do stack! And Werner, you're wonderful!  [Thank you Werner and Hupfer!]

Comment: @kando: For reference see [Master and slave counters](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-addtoreset.html).

Comment: Why `\@addtoreset{equation}{subparagraph}` is not sufficient?

Comment: @touhami: Because the counters are only linked to the level above them. That is, `subparagraph` is only linked to the stepping of `paragraph`, and `paragraph` to the stepping of `subsubsection`.