# References that include section/appendix heading id?

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multilevel figure / table numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/how-to-create-multilevel-figure-table-numbers)
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

dude see Fig. \ref{myfig} ! 

\appendix{}

\section{my section heading}\label{sec:seclabel}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{mycaption}
\label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

yields `dude see Fig. 1` -- how do i make something that yields `dude see Fig. A.1` (without manually doing `Fig. \ref{sec:seclabel}.\ref{myfig})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` macro. It needs `amsmath` package, see the complete example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% HERE!!!
\begin{document}

dude see Fig. \ref{myfig} ! 

\appendix{}

\numberwithin{figure}{section} %% AND HERE!!!

\section{my section heading}\label{sec:seclabel}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{mycaption}
\label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```