# Defining 'scheme' as a caption whilst using Tufte book

Tags: floats, captions, tufte, chemistry

I'm currently writing my thesis using the `tufte-book` class, and have been told that captions *must* go underneath the figures/tables/schemes (I know this goes against the point, but I can't really do anything about that right now, and plan on printing myself a less-ugly version along with the one conforming to the office guidelines).

Using previous questions here, I've been able to define a new environment for `pagefigure` which re-defines the `figure*` environment, in order to force the caption below the figure (I've also set this up for table etc.).

As a MWE, the code below shows the additional preamble I've added to get this to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, symmetric,justified,notoc, nobib]{tufte-book}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@tufte@margtab\@tufte@margtabfalse
\AtBeginEnvironment{margintable}{\@tufte@margtabtrue}
\AtEndEnvironment{margintable}{\@tufte@margtabfalse}
\newcommand{\classiccaptionstyle}{%
    \long\def\@caption##1[##2]##3{%
        \par
        \addcontentsline{\csname ext@##1\endcsname}{##1}%
        {\protect\numberline{\csname the##1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces ##2}}%
        \begingroup
        \@parboxrestore
        \if@minipage
        \@setminipage
        \fi
        \normalsize
        \@makecaption{\csname fnum@##1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces ##3}\par
        \endgroup}
    \long\def\@makecaption##1##2{%
        \vskip\abovecaptionskip
        \sbox\@tempboxa{\@tufte@caption@font##1: ##2}%
        \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        \@tufte@caption@font\if@tufte@margtab\@tufte@caption@justification\fi##1: ##2\par
        \else
        \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
        \fi
        \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
    %   \setcaptionfont{\normalfont}
    \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
    \let\label\@tufte@orig@label}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{pagefigure}{%
    \begin{figure*}[b!]
    \classiccaptionstyle
  }{\end{figure*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pagefigure}
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{graphics/example.eps}
  \caption{A Scheme which should take up the full width of the page }
\end{page figure}

\end{document}
```

What I now need is to be able to define a 'scheme' in addition to a 'figure' or a table.

I thought I might be able to do this by renewing the figurename to scheme, as below, however this messes up the numbering (Scheme 1.1, figure 1.2 rather than scheme 1.1, figure 1.1...).

```
\renewcommand\figurename{Scheme}
```

I've also tried defining a new environment, as below, but again this doesn't give the desired numbering.

```
\newenvironment{pagescheme}{%
    \begin{figure*}[b!]
 \renewcommand\figurename{Scheme}
    \classiccaptionstyle
  }{\end{figure*}}
```

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated. Ideally it needs to be by *duplicating* the pagefigure environment and changing the captioning for anything in that environment. Packages that define a new `scheme` environment from scatch lose the tufte floating (i.e. they span into the wrong margin uncontrollably).

---

I realise the obvious solution to this is to use the `chemstyle` package, but for various reasons this isn't compatible with the tufte document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, symmetric,justified,notoc, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  modules = {scheme}
}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newenvironment{marginscheme}[1][-1.2ex]
    {\@tufte@margin@float[#1]{scheme}}
    {\end@tufte@margin@float}
  \renewenvironment{scheme}[1][htbp]
    {\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi\@tufte@float[#1]{scheme}{}}
    {\end@tufte@float}
  \renewenvironment{scheme*}[1][htbp]%
    {\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi\@tufte@float[#1]{scheme}{star}}
    {\end@tufte@float}
  \renewcommand\listofschemes{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@class}{book}}%
      {\chapter*{\listschemename}}%
      {\section*{\listschemename}}%
      \@starttoc{los}%
  }
  \let\l@scheme\l@figure
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{scheme}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{An example caption.}
  \label{sch:example}
\end{scheme}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt seem to do what I was looking for (although it does sort out the numbering issue which is great!), I was needed the caption to go below, as I'd re-defined for the `pagescheme` environment in my MWE.    Due to the size of the schemes, they need to take the full-width of the page (i.e. also expand into the margin, which is what figure* is defined as by the tufte-book class).

Comment: @Chemistry this defines a `scheme` and `scheme*` analoguous to the existing `figure` and `figure*` in tufte-latex. Any modifcations you did to `figure` should now be equally possible with the new `scheme` environment…

Comment: I think the issue is the same as with the `chemstyle` issue, the *way* in which it defines scheme messes with the tufte class, and causes the scheme to now overflow into the wrong margin. I should edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Chemistry the code above produces an *exact* copy of tufte-latex's `figure`: the only thing I did was copying the definitions from the source and replaced `figure` with `scheme`!

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed a line when I pasted it across. That works perfectly! (also, I hadn't discovered chemmacros before, just had a browse through the docs and it has a lot of great things).

Comment: As an aside (feel free to tell me to just ask a new question), I can't see an obvious way of making the numbering 1.1...1.n, 2.1....2.n, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: @Chemistry `\numberwithin{scheme}{chapter}` (from `amsmath`) or `\counterwithin{scheme}{chapter}` (from `chngcntr`) and `\renewcommand\thescheme{\thechapter.\arabic{scheme}}`

Comment: @Chemistry this has been asked more than once already, *e.g.*, here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/